# lit element CDN bundle file: accessing a function contained in the cdn bundle file inside typescript file

Tags: typescript, web-component, cdn, rollupjs, lit

I have created a simple lit element bundle file using rollup.config.js. This bundle file is uploaded in Netstorage. This is what my lit element looks like:

```
import {customElement} from "lit/decorators.js";
import {LitElement} from "lit";

@customElement('my-lit-element')
export class MyLitElement extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('this is test log');
  }

  /**
   * invoked when a component is added to the document's DOM
   */
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
  }

    testMethod() {
      console.log('Hi from testMethod()');
    }

}

declare global {
  interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    'my-lit-element': MyLitElement;
  }
}
```

my rollup.config.json:

```
import merge from 'deepmerge';
import { createSpaConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json"

// import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import pkg from './package.json'
 
const baseConfig = createSpaConfig({
  developmentMode: process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH === 'true',
  injectServiceWorker: false
});
 
export default merge(baseConfig, {
  // any <script type="module"> inside will be bundled by rollup
  input: './index.html',
  plugins: [
    // ... other rollup plugins
    json()
  ]
});
```

I want to access testMethod() inside a typescript file in angular. I have tried accessing the function in an html file and it works like this:

```
<script type="module" src="https:path_to_my-lit-element-cdn_bundleFile.js"></script>
 <my-lit-element></my-lit-element>

<script>
  const el = document.querySelector('my-lit-element');
  const ob = customElements.whenDefined('my-lit-element').then(() => {

    //works
    el.testMethod()

    }
  });
```

But I want to be able to call the same thing in a typescript file

I have tried to directly access like this:

in index.html:

and in typescript file, I tried to accessing the testMethod() in the same way.

```
const el = document.querySelector('my-lit-element');
  const ob = customElements.whenDefined('my-lit-element').then(() => {

    //works
    el.testMethod()

    }
  });
```

but it does not work, any time I type  el.testMethod(), it starts complaining

```
Property 'testMethod' does not exist on type 'Element'.
```

Can anyone help me in determining how to call methods inside of cdn js file inside typescript file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typescript issue. You can use `HTMLElementTagNameMap` global interface to provide customElement types.

Define interface to associate all the web components public methods and properties.

```
export interface MyLitComponent extends HTMLElement {
       testMethod():void;
      //Define all the web component properties
}
```

Define `HTMLElementTagNameMap` inside global interface so that you can use the web component selector in TypeScript as if it were a regular HTML element

```
declare global {
          interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
            'my-lit-element': MyLitComponent;
          }
}
```

Now the querySelector return type would be `MyLitComponent`

```
const el = document.querySelector('my-lit-element'); //MyLitComponent
  const ob = customElements.whenDefined('my-lit-element').then(() => {
    el.testMethod()
  }
});
```

[**Example**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAcygewEYyog3sRRASwDsAXMOAMxgiQAkAVAWQBkBRKMAWzHMZjIAcjF7MYABzwFCiAOTcAngFooRMsrBde5OQC5EzRa3UBhNNwloSfMgG4ZAX2DPgwMAA8rcMsXKUaOkNjMwsrG3JETwoSEABnRCY2Th5baVkKOLJmMDIACzQQAAoASj0ANzQiEAdXCGssqK5EAF5EEDQIAFcdMgA6AEcuykUAZS1IMjQ4IoUVNQ0J3rkSu0QAenWjEzJzS2tbYHqSRsxWxG6sixTeuL6Adzy%20ABEwKlIwYrnVdU1tWxWfXyfCKpVaAD50rJoRMAPxAsBZHL5QqlBzQwjOVZuIA)